# Receiving error "You must call removeView() on the child's parent first"

Tags: android, dynamic, row, tablelayout

The above error occurred while I try to add row dynamically to my tableview
Main code of activity. I have tried many solutions available in stack overflow. But nothing solved my problem.

```
package com.example.bhramaram.myapplication;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TableLayout;
import android.widget.TableRow;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.bhramaram.myapplication.Dbhelper;
import com.example.bhramaram.myapplication.R;

public class jav extends AppCompatActivity {
    TableLayout tb;
    TableRow tableRow;
    Dbhelper dbhelper;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        int day=0;
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.timetable);
        getvalues();
    }

    private void getvalues() {

        tb=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.timetble);
        TextView textView1,textView2,textView3,textView4,textView5,textView0;
        textView0=new TextView(this);textView1=new TextView(this);
        textView2=new TextView(this);textView3=new TextView(this);
        textView4=new TextView(this);textView5=new TextView(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        textView0.setLayoutParams(lp);textView1.setLayoutParams(lp);
        textView2.setLayoutParams(lp);textView3.setLayoutParams(lp);
        textView4.setLayoutParams(lp);textView5.setLayoutParams(lp);
        dbhelper= new Dbhelper(jav.this);
        Cursor cursor= dbhelper.recieveData();

        if(cursor.getCount()==0){
            alert("Nothing","Nothing to show");
            return;}
        int i=0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext())
        {
            tableRow=new TableRow(this);

            TableLayout.LayoutParams lp1=new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            textView0.setText((cursor.getString(0)));textView1.setText((cursor.getString(1)));
            textView2.setText((cursor.getString(2)));textView3.setText((cursor.getString(3)));
            textView4.setText((cursor.getString(4)));textView5.setText((cursor.getString(5)));
            tableRow.setLayoutParams(lp);
            //Error occurred here
            tableRow.addView(textView0);tableRow.addView(textView1);
            tableRow.addView(textView2);tableRow.addView(textView3);
            tableRow.addView(textView4);tableRow.addView(textView5);
            tb.addView(tableRow,lp1);

        }



    }

    private void alert(String title, String alert) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setCancelable(true);
        builder.setTitle(title);
        builder.setMessage(alert);
    }


}
```

corresponding layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/timetble"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">
    </TableLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Error details

> Process: com.example.bhramaram.myapplication, PID: 14266
>                     java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.bhramaram.myapplication/com.example.bhramaram.myapplication.jav}: 'java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.'
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4460)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4301)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4241)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4214)
>                         at com.example.bhramaram.myapplication.jav.getvalues(jav.java:60)
>                         at com.example.bhramaram.myapplication.jav.onCreate(jav.java:29)
>                         at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6705)
>                         at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)

Why am I getting this error?

Also I am a newcomer to Android developers community. This project is about an app that uses local SQLite database to store and display time table. I follow the method which I found from the web to show the results in table. It will be helpful to me if you can suggest more efficient methods for this code snippet.

Comment: `'java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.` Isn't it clear?!

Answer (score 2):

Here, you create the text views:

```
TextView textView1,textView2,textView3,textView4,textView5,textView0;
textView0=new TextView(this);textView1=new TextView(this);
textView2=new TextView(this);textView3=new TextView(this);
textView4=new TextView(this);textView5=new TextView(this);
```

Then, inside the loop, you are adding the same `TextView` into a `TableRow` several times:

```
tableRow.addView(textView0);tableRow.addView(textView1);
tableRow.addView(textView2);tableRow.addView(textView3);
tableRow.addView(textView4);tableRow.addView(textView5);
tb.addView(tableRow,lp1);
```

Since those `TextView` were already added to a row before, they already have a parent view and cause the error that you mentioned.

In order to fix, you must move the `new TextView()` part into the loop. You must create new objects for each loop iteration:

```
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    tableRow=new TableRow(this);

    TableLayout.LayoutParams lp1=new TableLayout.LayoutParams(TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

    // Create new objects before adding them
    textView0=new TextView(this);textView1=new TextView(this);
    textView2=new TextView(this);textView3=new TextView(this);
    textView4=new TextView(this);textView5=new TextView(this);

    textView0.setText((cursor.getString(0)));textView1.setText((cursor.getString(1)));
    textView2.setText((cursor.getString(2)));textView3.setText((cursor.getString(3)));
    textView4.setText((cursor.getString(4)));textView5.setText((cursor.getString(5)));
    tableRow.setLayoutParams(lp);

    tableRow.addView(textView0);tableRow.addView(textView1);
    tableRow.addView(textView2);tableRow.addView(textView3);
    tableRow.addView(textView4);tableRow.addView(textView5);
    tb.addView(tableRow,lp1);
}
```